# ZEBRA ZPL label formats prints quotations along with text

Tags: zpl

In our space we use an ACUCOBOL-GT written program which pushes variables such as PHY NAME to a written format. The program then replaces said PHY NAME with the actual name of the pharmacy and then cups pushes the data onto the label, producing an readable output. We use zebra printers with EPL written label formats to print out these pharmacy medication labels.

Recently I wrote a format using ZPL to produce the same label as Im able to customize the data better than with the old EPL.

The only issue Im running into is that now with the ZPL the data prints onto the label between quotation marks.

So instead of it being eg Montagu Pharmacy it prints out as "Montagu Pharmacy          ".

an example of the old EPL code is as follow : PHY NAME A010,025,0,4,1,1,N,

and the output of said code is as follow : A010,025,0,4,1,1,N,"MONTAGU PHARMACY               "

on the output before printing it shows the quotes as well but as soon as you send it to the printer it removes the quotes and prints without them.

Here is an example of the ZPL code : PHY NAME ^FO100,025,0^A0N,18,30^FD

and here is the output of said code : PHY NAME ^FO100,025,0^A0N,18,30^FD"Montagu Pharmacy        "

on the output before printing it shows the quotes and when it prints out onto the label it prints the text along with the quotes.

I understand that the ACUCOBOL-GT program creates the data with the quotations but the EPL never printed them out but the ZPL does.

Is there anything Im doing wrong or that I can do to remove the quotes so that it can print out normally as before.

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Kind regards

Hans Steyn

Answer (score 0):

This is because in EPL the `"DATA"` to be printed is surrounded by quotes(`"`), while in ZPL it is not, so quotes are printed. You need to remove the quotes as follows:

```
PHY NAME ^FO100,025,0^A0N,18,30^FDMontagu Pharmacy
```

References:

EPL *(`A` command)*
https://www.servopack.de/support/zebra/EPL2_Manual.pdf

page 41

ZPL *(`^FD` command)*
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

page 172

**EDIT 1**
As per your comment, AFAIK there is no way to remove the quotes *after* the command reaches the printer. So the only way is to have your supplier's software send the command to some custom tool/software you have that will strip the quotes then relay the message to the printer.

```
[supplier software] -> [custom software] -> [Printer]
```

I don't know their software, but they could generate a text file that your custom tool would load and remove the quotes for example with a regex like this, that even allows for escaped quotes in the middle of the name if there are any (*arrows*):

[image: quotes regex]

This being said, it is quite surprising that removing quotes requires massive development, especially because they already seem able to generate both EPL and ZPL.

Comment: Unfortunately the program sending the code is hardcoded and requires massive development by the company who owns it and they wont change it as there are so any customers out there still using EPL. 

So is there no other way in which i can remove those quotes before it reaches the printer?